# Create a Progress Bar (without %) between two Activities, until load the content of the Second Activity

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a Main Activity with a button, pressing that button opens a second Activity. This second Activity loads a large amount of data from Firebase to a RecyclerView that takes some time. When I clicked on the Main Activity button, I wanted to open a page with a Progress Bar (without showing the percentage) and only when the second Activity was completely loaded did the Progress Bar close and show the content of the second Activity. What is the best way to do this? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ProgressBar` in xml layout file(in the fragment/activity where you need to display), like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

and in the associated activity file, set the visibility to `GONE`.
do this where you called a method to load data.

```
progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
```

if you can add that part of the code to your question, then it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I did what you said. That was what I wanted. I used constraintLayout.setVisibility (View.GONE) and constraintLayout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE).

Answer (score 0):

When you switch the second activitiy in onCreate method, if you implement the progress bar programmatically set it to infinite after instantiate it and add it to view hierarcy. Then when your data is done in the background just hide using View.GONE attribute Assuming you use Java and vertical linear layout.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
yourLinearLayout.addView(progressBar);
...
// Once your data has been loaded hide the progress bar
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// Or remove it
yourLinearLayout.removeView(progressBar);
```